# which repository will maven choose inside settings.xml

Tags: maven

If I define two repositories in my settings.xml, which repositories will maven choose during build?
Like below, codehausSnapshots1 or codehausSnapshots2 ?

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <repositories>
      <repository>
        <id>codehausSnapshots1</id>
        ......
      <repository/>
      <repository>
        <id>codehausSnapshots2</id>
        ......
      <repository/>
    </repositories>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: According to me, it will use the first repository where the dependency looked up is found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is using both of them. There is a certain order which repository maven looks first, what next and so on. If Maven fails to download artifact from the first repo, it will try download it from the next repo. Maven looks repositories first from settings.xml, then project's pom.xml and lastly parent pom's repositories. Also, order of declared repositories matter. In this example, maven looks codehausSnapshots1 repository first as it is declared before codehausSnapshots2.